# Jquery not found with kendoUI

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I keep getting an error that states `jQuery not found`.  Normally this is due to jquery not loading before things that need it.  However, when I look at the debugger jquery is being loaded first. What might I be missing to not get jquery to load first?

Relevant bundles

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery")
       .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js")
       .Include("~/Scripts/knockout-{version}.js")
       .Include("~/Scripts/moment.js")               
);

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/kendo")
       .Include("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.3.1316/kendo.all.min.js")
       .Include("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.3.1316/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")
);
```

Before the closing `</body>` one the _Layout.cshtml page

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")
```

page source information

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/knockout-3.0.0.debug.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/kendo/2013.3.1316/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/kendo/2013.3.1316/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
```

found a solution if I moved `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` to the header it works.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, the reason jQuery needs to be in the header is that the MVC helpers inject `<script>` tags directly below the widget element. something like

```
<script>jQuery(function(){ //widget init code here })</script>
```

since jQuery was being loaded below the `body` tag the widget code (like above) was executing before jQuery was loaded, hence the error. You could also solve this problem by using the `Widget.Defer()` feature alongside `Kendo.WriteScripts()` which allow you to defer the script tags until after the jQuery script tag

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-complete-for-asp-net-mvc/general-discussions/kendo-initialization-scripts-in-body-interfere-with-other-libraries.aspx